# Android MediaPlayer stops after playing 1 minute in background

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I am playing an audio stream from mediaPlayer using a service but it stops playing the song after approx one minute of being in the background or the screen turned off. While on the other hand it works fine and completes the song when the appication is kept open.

```
public class MyService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    String audio_stream;
    Context context;

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        audio_stream = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audio_stream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                return false;
            }
        });
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.d("Channel", audio_stream+"he");
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }else{
            Log.d("channel", "this is the case");
        }

    }




    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

**Before MediaPlayer stops, it gives 4 lines in the log which are**

```
V/MediaPlayer: resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer: cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
V/MediaPlayer: resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer: cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
```

I am unable to understand where the problem is exactly and how can I proceed to overcome it.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Android 8.0 and higher devices, you need to have this be [a foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services), with an associated `Notification`. Otherwise, your service will be stopped after a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Is correct! on Android 8.0 and higher devices must have a foreground service with a notification. I had the same problem and it was solved this way.

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    createNotificationChanel();

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);


        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"chanelId1" )
                .setContentTitle("Neville")
                .setContentText("Esto es un texto")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_item)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
//.......

    return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void createNotificationChanel(){
            //Chequeando si la versión de Adroid es Oreo o superior:
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
    
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("chanelId1","Foreground Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    
                NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    
            }
```